# Validating a font name

Tags: c++11, direct3d

I've got an abstraction over a Direct3D9 ID3DXFont object. When setting the font name, how can I verify that the font name is valid without having to create a font object and find out the hard way? I checked the link about logical fonts and there doesn't seem to be anything in there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [EnumFontFamiliesEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162620%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) would help you here?

Namely:

> If set to DEFAULT_CHARSET, the
>   function enumerates all uniquely-named
>   fonts in all character sets. (If there
>   are two fonts with the same name, only
>   one is enumerated.)